# Android - How to avoid system's onClick?

Tags: android, onclick, android-imageview

I Have a `GrinView` with costum `Adapter` that defines some `ImageViews` and set `onClick` event. When the user clicks the buttons it show some orange background, as the iimage bellow. How can I avoid this background display?
[image: the background display]

Comment: Apply logic found here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5727845/771072

Comment: @Bororo I tried to use `setBackgroundResource` with my own selector, but the orange backgrounnd still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting

```
android:background="@null"
```

in your layout xml.

Are you sure you are using a ImageView with onClickListener? If you are using an ImageButton, try changing it into a ImageView (that doesn't bring onClick-animation).

Cheers

Comment: I'm actually declaring the `imageView` via code, I sure i use `imageView `(actually with onItemClickListener) and `setBackgroundResource(0)` does not help.

Comment: ok, then the onClick-behaviour might be coming from your GridView. Try setting android:listSelector="#00000000" (transparent selector) in the layout of your GridView.